# Do i need to write extra code for newly added youtube video in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am new in iPhone development. I want to create an app which will show youtube videos those i will upload in my account.

I will have admin panel in my app, from where i could control my videos. Suppose i developed the app and launched on app world.

Now after some time I want to add new videos to my account , should i need to write extra code or it will reflect automatically via used link in iphone app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speaking generally, you could have the application find your newest videos released in Youtube and display them in the app.  Therefore, you would not need to have any more code.

There would be no code for any video within your app.  Instead, have your app get the list of the videos from Youtube and play them.